# Auto changes of css in cherry framework in wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress

i have used this template http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/50494.html

when i am doing the changes of css it is working but after some time it automatically revert the all my changes and give me the default css.

Theme is in cherry framework anyone has any idea how can i stop it or how can i do my the css changes in this theme

I have put my question in template monster but they did not respond me yet.

Comment: Do you use any caching plugin?

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same problem.Then put my custom css codes in theme options. then not reverted.

Below you can see the list of reasons that cause issues with CSS changes (like reverting changes performed to template styles).

```
-Changes were performed in CherryFramework files instead of themeXXXXX child theme files.

-Changes were performed in main-style.css file.

-Changes performed in themeXXXXX/style.css file without declaration of !important property.

-Changes performed in Custom CSS section were not saved before updating CherryFramework and were not put back and saved after update.
```

IMPORTANT: All CSS changes should be performed in child theme. Usually it is called like themeXXXXX. Please DO NOT perform changes in CherryFramework folder as all changes will be lost after CherryFramework update.

1-style.css – the main CSS file. It is required for the correct theme functionality, you can also add custom CSS styles here.

2-style.less – the .less file with the theme CSS styles.

3-main-style.css – the CSS file with the theme styles. It is generated automatically from style.less file, that is why you
SHOULD NOT perform changes in main-style.css file.

You can find more info from here.
http://info.template-help.com/help/wordpress-cherry-framework-keeps-reverting-my-css-changes.html

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old feed, but thought I'd add my 2c.  I've also faced the same problem -- If you can, edit all css in the Cherry Options.  Only edit in main-style.css if that doesn't work.  Cherry Options CSS overwrites all but inline css.  As soon as cherry options (custom css or any changes or even just hitting save) will cause all changes to main-style.css to be lost.

Once you save anything to main-style.css no cherry options can be altered or your css will be lost.

Answer (score 0):

When you move website containing cherry frame work

Follow below steps
Remove blow files from child theme. 
1. theme root/style.less.cache
2. bootstrap/less/bootstrap.less.cache

Remove these 2 files and your theme will work smoothly.

Comment: You might want to edit your post—you seem to have wanted a list on multiple lines, but it didn't turn out that way. I'd fix it, but I don't know what you intended.